# jQuery - delay each div in DOM

Tags: jquery, delay, fadeout

I'm trying to 
loop over each DIV in DOM and apply an effect (let's say `fadeOut()`), with time spaces between each one.
From some reason this thing doesn't want to work.

```
var stupid = -1000;

return_stupid = function(){
return stupid+=1000;
}

$(function(){
    $("div").not("#wrapper").delay(return_stupid()).queue(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

edit:
Well, I found the issue. 
return_stupid() is only called ONCE because it's not a .each() statement.

Well, I don't wanna use each(), it's eating the memory!

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery plugin as below. It will fade out each matched element between a given interval.

```
$.fn.fadetraining = function(duration, delay) {
  var $elements = this;
  $elements.length && $elements.first().fadeOut(duration, function(){
    $elements.slice(1).delay(delay).fadetraining(duration);
  });
  return $elements;
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
$("div").not("#wrapper").fadetraining("slow", 1000);
```

[**You can see it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/c4k5m/)

I don't understand why you don't want to use `.each()`. After all, almost all jQuery function use it internally.

**Note:** This is a spin-off of a previously written jQuery plugin of mine, [`$.fn.fadetrain`](https://github.com/aeurielesn/jQuery.fn/tree/master/%24.fn.fadetrain).

Comment: I don't really know what I don't want to use it. Seems like selecting $("div") is much faster than running each div

Comment: @GalWeissman, either way, I'm afraid you can't apply the animation you want without accessing *each* div individually :)

Comment: Actually, I wanted to trigger the fadeOut for all elements simultaneously, not waiting for another one to finish but execute them all with 100 milliseconds difference from each other

Comment: @GalWeissman, if you insist then you already have your answer, you have to use `.each()`

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be using delay wrong. Try something like this:

```
$(".cell").animate({width:"100px",height:"100px"}, 3000).delay(1000).fadeOut();
```

I've made a JSFiddle as an example. http://jsfiddle.net/M9n8a/1/